# Sharing a Printer from a Mac to AirPrint

Tags: airprint

While I am aware that you can use handyPrint for this.. you have to pay for it to keep using it.. and I have no Paypal or Credit Cards.

Does anyone know a method so when a Printer is shared on your Mac, it broadcasts it as AirPrint so I can print from iOS with it like you could handyPrint. Possibly using a modded CUPS server or change a couple Bonjour plists or something?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.howtogeek.com/102671/how-to-enable-airprint-for-ios-printing-from-any-mac-or-windows-pc/

Thanks to AirPrint Hacktivator you can turn any printer connected to your Mac or Windows PC into an AirPrint compatible printer.  from:
http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/01/make-any-printer-airprint-compatible/

Comment: AirPrint Hacktivator is now handyPrint, and it isn't free anymore...

Comment: Well.. I can always see if Brother's app will work, as mine is a Brother machine.. any ideas to actually make it AirPrint without paying?